# Sort a set by one of its attributes

Tags: java, set

I have a set of users like this.

```
Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

User contains first name, last name and age. I need to sort users according to first name. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() { // Implementation });

Comment: I don't think Collections.sort works on Sets, just Lists. What you could do is use a "TreeSet" instead of a HashSet and provide a comparator in the constructor. When you iterate through the set, it will always be ordered.

Comment: Bret is right.  Collections.sort doesn't work on Sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. HashSets (like HashMaps) are unordered.

Use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead. It orders elements according to their [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or using an explicit [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Comparator<User> firstNameComparator = new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
        return u1.getFirstName().compareTo(u2.getFirstName());
    }
};

Set<User> usersSorted = new TreeSet<User>(firstNameComparator);
usersSorted.addAll(users);
```